# Android Geofencing API working fine for wifi in the background but not for GPS

Tags: android, google-api-client, geofencing, android-gps, android-geofence

I am Working with the GeofencingClient Api. The problem with that my application is working fine when wifi is turned on and triggering the geofence transition.
But in case of GPS its not working.
I want that the service keeps working fine in the background and keeps triggering the geofence transitions when it enters and leaves the geofence set radius.

Some Sample code

The code where I am calling the GeofencingClient

```
  public static void addGeofences() {
    mGeofenceList = new ArrayList<>();
    populateGeofenceList();

    mGeofencingClient = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(MyApplicationClass.getAppContext());


    mGeofencingClient.addGeofences(getGeofencingRequest(), getGeofencePendingIntent())
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    Log.d("Tag", "Test");
                }
            });
}
```

The code where this method is called addGeofence

```
public class GpsLocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements LocationListener {

    LocationManager locationManager ;
    boolean GpsStatus ;
    public Context mContext;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        MainActivity obj = new MainActivity();

        locationManager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        GpsStatus = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if(GpsStatus == true)
        {

            Toast.makeText(context, "GPS Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            obj. populateGeofenceList();
            obj.mGeofencingClient = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(context);
            obj.addGeofences();


        }else {

            Toast.makeText(context, "Disabled GPS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }
}
```

And the code where this transition happens

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);

     Context context;

    if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
        String errorMessage = GeofenceErrorMessages.getErrorString(this,
                geofencingEvent.getErrorCode());
        Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
        return;
    }

    // Get the transition type.
    int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();


    //===============================

    if (geofenceTransition == 1) {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                attendenInRecord();

            }
        });
        Log.i(TAG, "Entered");

    }

    else {

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                attendenOutRecord();

            }
        });
        Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(geofenceTransition));
    }
    //===================================

    // Test that the reported transition was of interest.
    if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
            geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {


        // Get the geofences that were triggered. A single event can trigger multiple geofences.
        List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();

        // Get the transition details as a String.
        String geofenceTransitionDetails = getGeofenceTransitionDetails(geofenceTransition,
                triggeringGeofences);

        // Send notification and log the transition details.
        sendNotification(geofenceTransitionDetails);


        Log.i(TAG, geofenceTransitionDetails);

        if(geofenceTransition==Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER){

            Log.i(TAG, geofenceTransitionDetails);
        }

    } else {
        // Log the error.
        Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.geofence_transition_invalid_type, geofenceTransition));

    }
}

/**
 * Gets transition details and returns them as a formatted string.
 *
 * @param geofenceTransition    The ID of the geofence transition.
 * @param triggeringGeofences   The geofence(s) triggered.
 * @return                      The transition details formatted as String.
 */
private String getGeofenceTransitionDetails(
        int geofenceTransition,
        List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences) {

    String geofenceTransitionString = getTransitionString(geofenceTransition);

    // Get the Ids of each geofence that was triggered.
    ArrayList<String> triggeringGeofencesIdsList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Geofence geofence : triggeringGeofences) {
        triggeringGeofencesIdsList.add(geofence.getRequestId());
    }
    String triggeringGeofencesIdsString = TextUtils.join(", ",  triggeringGeofencesIdsList);

    return geofenceTransitionString + ": " + triggeringGeofencesIdsString;
}

/**
 * Posts a notification in the notification bar when a transition is detected.
 * If the user clicks the notification, control goes to the MainActivity.
 */
private void sendNotification(String notificationDetails) {
    // Get an instance of the Notification manager
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Android O requires a Notification Channel.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.app_name);
        // Create the channel for the notification
        NotificationChannel mChannel =
                new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

        // Set the Notification Channel for the Notification Manager.
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }

    // Create an explicit content Intent that starts the main Activity.
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

    // Construct a task stack.
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

    // Add the main Activity to the task stack as the parent.
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);

    // Push the content Intent onto the stack.
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

    // Get a PendingIntent containing the entire back stack.
    PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // Get a notification builder that's compatible with platform versions >= 4
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    // Define the notification settings.
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.point)
            // In a real app, you may want to use a library like Volley
            // to decode the Bitmap.
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.point))
            .setColor(Color.RED)
            .setContentTitle(notificationDetails)
            .setContentText(getString(R.string.geofence_transition_notification_text))
            .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent);

    // Set the Channel ID for Android O.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        builder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID); // Channel ID
    }

    // Dismiss notification once the user touches it.
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);

    // Issue the notification
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
}

/**
 * Maps geofence transition types to their human-readable equivalents.
 *
 * @param transitionType    A transition type constant defined in Geofence
 * @return                  A String indicating the type of transition
 */
private String getTransitionString(int transitionType) {
    switch (transitionType) {

        case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER:


            return getString(R.string.geofence_transition_entered);

        case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT:

            return getString(R.string.geofence_transition_exited);
        default:
            return getString(R.string.unknown_geofence_transition);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you requesting fine location?

Comment: ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

Answer (score 1):

Try this with requesting fine location with the GPS. i find that when using coarse location the gps fences don't get triggered, but with wifi they will know that you are within a certain range.

I understand that fused location will help this immensely to 1 meter next year when google releases wifiRTT.  Either way you'll need to request fine location which encompasses coarse location as well.

Comment: Thanks reidisaki . I have tried with the fine_location but in the background service it is still not working without wifi. I want it to work with gps too.

Comment: in the location settings of the app is the setting set to high accuracy?. not balanced, or power saving? this is in the android OS level of location settings

Comment: When I am in the foreground the application is running fine for both but in background GPS is having problem.

Comment: reidisaki I have my setting set to high accuracy
When I am calling the addGeofence method in onCreate of activity both are running fine But when I am calling it in a servie its having problem in case of GPS

Comment: just wante dto confirm you are trying to add a geofence in a service?

Comment: Yes I am adding geofence in service